# Solving for $x$ in $\tan(3x) \tan (2x)= 1$

Tags: trigonometry

> If
>   $$\tan(3x) \tan(2x)= 1$$
>   Then $x$ is equal to

Attempt: I used the '$\tan$' identity but it showed no results.

The identity:

$$\frac{\tan(2x)+\tan(3x)}{1-\tan(2x)\tan(3x)}$$

Answer (score 9):

Hint:
$$\tan 3x\tan 2x=1$$
$$\implies \sin 3x \sin 2x= \cos 3x \cos 2x$$
$$\implies \cos 3x\cos 2x-\sin 3x\sin 2x=0$$
Can you see the $\cos(\alpha+\beta)$ identity?

Comment: Can you please check my answer ?

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way:

The equation is the same as $$\tan3x=\cot 2x=\tan(90-2x)$$
$$\Rightarrow 3x=90-2x+n.180$$
$$\Rightarrow x=18+n.36$$

Answer (score 2):

Is this correct ?

$1 - \tan{2x}\tan{3x}=0$

$\therefore\frac{\tan{2x} + \tan{3x}}{1 - \tan{2x}\tan{3x}}= \text{undefined}$

$\therefore\tan{5x}=\text{undefined}$

$\therefore\tan{5x}=\tan{\frac{\pi}2}\;\text{or}\;\tan{\frac{3\pi}2}$

$\therefore 5x=90^\circ\;\text{or}\;270 ^\circ$

$\therefore x=18^\circ\;\text{or}\;54 ^\circ$

Comment: http://web2.0calc.com/ suggests it is correct, but somebody please check it.

Comment: correct ${}{}{}$